# Copiar de uma planilha para outra

Tags: excel-vba

Estou tentando realizar este código mas o excel retorna erro de execução 1004 na linha 4 (marcada com **) poderiam me fornecer alguma ajuda sobre o motivo disto acontecer?

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To 367
    Sheets("Plan").Select
        If Cells(i, 1).Value = Date Then         **
             
            Sheets("Dólar").Range("B2").Copy
            Sheets("Plan1").Cells(i, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            
        End If
     Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

quer copiar o valor que esta na célula correto ?
Pelo que entendi só quer copiar o valor então poderá usar o seguinte código:

```
For i = 0 To 367 step 1
    if Excel.Workbooks("nomeficheiro").Worksheets("List").Cells(i, 2).value = Date then
               Excel.Workbooks("nomeficheiro").Worksheets("List_2").Cells(i, 2) = Excel.Workbooks("nomeficheiro").Worksheets("List").Cells(i, 2)
             end if
 next
```

- Excel.Workbooks("nomeficheiro").Worksheets("List").Cells(i, 2).value -> valor que quer copiar
- Excel.Workbooks("nomeficheiro").Worksheets("List_2").Cells(i, 2) -> célula onde quer colocar o valor copiado. escolher a célula